# Invalid Info Type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

Getting the following error for the info type: ENCRYPTION_KEY.

> {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"Invalid built-in info type name \\"ENCRYPTION_KEY\\".\",\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n  }\n}\n","errorVerbose":"DLP non 200. Body: {\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"Invalid built-in info type name \\"ENCRYPTION_KEY\\".\",\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n  }

Is this a supported detector as mentioned on the dlp info type page? https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference#united_states

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug ... our documentation got updated before we were ready to launch that. Oops! For a source of truth, you can check https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dlp/v2/dlp.infoTypes.list?_h=1& as to what's available.